# get data from 2 connected JSON url in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I've got a problem with JSON in JavaScipt. I've got 2 different JSON URL. One of them contains data about users and the second one about posts. And in posts JSON I've got a field `userId`.

I want to find a way to connect them somehow. I need to get users and their posts and then count how many posts every user wrote.

```js
var postRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
postRequest.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
postRequest.onload = function() {
  var posts = JSON.parse(postRequest.responseText);

  var userRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  userRequest.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  userRequest.onload = function (){
    var users = JSON.parse(userRequest.responseText);
    for(k in users){
      document.write("</br></br>"+ users[k].name +", " + users[k].username + ", " + users[k].email + "</br>" + "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + "</br>");
      for(k1 in posts){
        if(posts[k1].userId===users[k].id){
          document.write(posts[k1].body + "</br>");
        }
      }
    }
  };
  userRequest.send();

};
postRequest.send();
```

but I think it doesn't look good. I want to get data from JSON to variable to use them later, in function for example. 
Anyone help? I've never connected data from 2 JSON files and want to do it in a good way and getting good practice.

Comment: Is your question mainly about making your code look nicer? You don't mention if your code works or not.

Comment: You may do this job at the server side by appropriately querying your db and save some bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead

```
for(k in users){
   for(k1 in posts){
      if(posts[k1].userId===users[k].id){
         if(!users[k].hasOwnProperty('posts')) {
             users[k].posts = [];
         }
         users[k].posts.push(posts[k1].body);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you could you jquery

```
$.when($.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
})).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=" + value.id
        }).then(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log("UserID:" + data[0].userId + "   Nos Posts:" + data.length);

        });
    });
});
```

You can try above code and let me know if it solve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

**Steps you can use :**

**1.** You can add a `body` property in to the objects in `users` array as per the `id` and `userid` match.

**2.** Later you can iterate the `users` array whenever you want to use.

**DEMO**

```js
var postRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
postRequest.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
postRequest.onload = function() {
  var posts = JSON.parse(postRequest.responseText);
  var userRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
  userRequest.open('GET', 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  userRequest.onload = function (){
    var users = JSON.parse(userRequest.responseText);
    
    for(k in users) {
      for(k1 in posts) {
        if(posts[k1].userId===users[k].id){
          users[k].body = posts[k1].body;
        }
      }
    }
    
    console.log("users", users);
  };
  userRequest.send();
};
postRequest.send();
```